# Window short cuts for XFCE4

Tags: linux, x11, window-managers, xfce

This is not a programming question per se, but this is certainly about something which would help increasing my programming productivity.

In KDE, one can assign short-cuts to particular windows. This eliminates alt-tabbing completely and, is very very convenient when multiple apps(browser, console, emacs etc) are open.
My question is - can window short cuts be assigned in XFCE4 ? And if yes, how ? I very recently switched to XFCE from KDE4 and would appreciate any help regarding this.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using xdotool.
For example command below moves Firefox to foreground:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --name 'Mozilla Firefox' windowraise
```

You can update your keyboard settings with needed parameters (Applications Menu -> Settings -> Settings Manager -> Keyboard):

[image]